# <f:attribute> not working inside <p:tab>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I want to access some parameters in my backing bean on tab click.I used  but i'm not able to fetch parameters from it.Here's my code:

```
<p:tabView>
<p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{maintab.tabchangelistener}" />
<c:forEach items="#{maintab.random}" var="field">
    <p:tab title="Title">
        <p:tabView  prependId="false" cache="false" dynamic="true">
            <p:tab title="ABC" style="outline: 0;">
                <f:attribute name="parameter" value="#{field.name}"/>
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
    </p:tab>
</c:forEach> 
</p:tabView>
```

My tabchangelistener function is :

```
public void tabchangelistener(TabChangeEvent event){
    String par=(String)event.getTab().getAttributes().get("parameter");
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a `<p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{bean.tabchangelistener}"/>`?

Comment: Your tabs are nested! So I doubt the attribute is passed on to the parent listener. Heck, it should not even fire changing a child tab

Comment: @Kukeltje so what would be the better approach to access the attributes. I even tried using f:attribute on parent tab still not able to access it

Comment: You did not speak for what purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest some javascript approach here using JSF pass-through attributes with the namespace *xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"*

Something as below:

```
<p:tabView 
 onTabChange="handleTabChange(index)"
 onTabShow="handleTabShow(index)">
  <c:forEach items="#{maintab.random}" var="field">
     <p:tab title="Title">
        <p:tabView  prependId="false" cache="false" dynamic="true">
            <p:tab title="ABC" style="outline: 0;" pt:data-name="#{field.name}" />
        </p:tabView>
     </p:tab>
  </c:forEach> 
</p:tabView>
```

Then, on the **javascript** functions **handleTabChange** and **handleTabShow**, you can just use some plain jQuery code to find the tab you want, and get the corresponding ***data-name*** pass-through attribute.

Once you have it, you can trigger some **<p:remoteCommand>** calling whatever action listener you want, passing the field as a parameter, so you can get it inside the action listener as a request parameter.

Something like:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="remoteTabActionListener" actionListener="#{maintab.tabActionlistener}" />

function handleTabShow(index) {
    var pass_through_field = $("expression to find the correct tab").attr("data-name");
    remoteTabActionListener([{name: 'my_field', value: pass_through_field}]);
}
```

So finally, in your java action listener, you can retrieve the field:

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Map<String, String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
String page = params.get("my_field");
```

Not sure if this will work, but maybe can give you some ideas on how to achieve your goal ...